# Confusion about complementation of an NP language with oracle and coNP with oracle

Tags: complexity-theory

Hello Stackexchangers,

I've come across a confusion in one of my exercises.

I was supposed to prove $\Pi_{n+1}^{p} = (\textit{co-NP})^{\Sigma_{n}^{p}}$, where the superscript operator in $M^{A}$ refers to a TM $M$ having access to an oracle in $A$.

I have two rules: $\Pi_{n+1}^{p} = co-\Sigma_{n+1}^p$ and $\Sigma_{n+1}^{p} = NP^{\Sigma_{n}^{p}}$. I understand we can simply do a substitution whereby $\Sigma_{n+1}^{p} = co-(NP^{\Sigma_{n}^{p}})$, but am confused as to what the brackets would mean. Is this the same as $(co-NP)^{\Sigma_{n}^{p}}$?

The former is a complement of the languages in NP having oracle access to $\Sigma_{n}^{p}$, but the latter is the set of languages where co-NP has oracle access to $\Sigma_{n}^{p}$. I was wondering if they are the same.